# Not getting data in the Laravel rapyd Datagrid

Tags: laravel

I'm using the Laravel [Rapyd](http://rapyd.com) DataGrid, and I have the following code:

```
public function getArticles()
    {
        $grid = DataGrid::source( Article::with("user"));
        $grid->link('/admin/article?create=1', "New Article",  "TR");
        $grid->add('title','Title', true);
        $grid->add('sef','Url');
        $grid->add('{{ $row->user->email }}','author');
        $grid->addActions('/admin/article');
        $grid->paginate(10);
        $grid = $grid->getGrid();
        return  View::make('admin.edit', array('content' => $grid));

    }
```

But this code does not output any row. There is only the table structure and a 'Create New' button, records are not appearing .

One more thing: can anyone please explain what does the following code do?

```
 $grid->add('sef','Url');
 $grid->add('{{ $row->user->email }}','author');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just an example, like this one:
http://www.rapyd.com/demo/grid

To get it work you must define some models (article, user) with correct relation bw.
**However this is just an example, you should use your models, your fields.**

Note that since DataGrid extends DataSet you can also avoid models passing a query builder:
`DataGrid::source( DB::table('articles')->select('title', 'description'))`
as explained here https://github.com/zofe/rapyd-laravel

The latest 2 field added in the sample you posted are again a demo about how you can add columns to the datagrid:
by name or by blade syntax,  in this case you can use {{$row->user->email}}  because the DG source has a relation  "with" user model so it's possible to show  user's fields using
 *$row->user->fieldname*